# How does one achieve in Windows 7 a level of security comparable to setting a file's permissions to 0600 in Unix?

Tags: security, permissions

I want to store securely the file `.pgpass`, which contains the authentication credentials (including passwords) for client programs to be able to log in to PostgreSQL servers.

The [Pg documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) specifies that, for Unix systems, one should set the permissions of this file to 0600.  For Windows systems, however, it gives no guidance whatsoever.  It merely say

> On Microsoft Windows, it is assumed that the file is stored in a directory that is secure...

How does one typically achieve the same effect of Unix's 0600 file permissions setting on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent because the Unix and NTFS permission models are not the same.

Comment: If I create a file and give the user read and write permissions and an explicit deny to all other users, I am giving them the same effective permissions as a chmod 600 command on Linux.

Comment: Not exactly. It might accomplish what you need, but in NTFS the owner always has full control of the file. 0600 is the owner only has read/write.

Comment: I edited my post to (hopefully) minimize the possibility of overly literal (i.e. completely unproductive) interpretations of it, such as the one implicit in this answer.

Comment: @Davidw: Thanks for your comment; I'm glad to see that at least one person gets it.